# FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I want to check if a user is logged-in in facebook using the Facebook JavaScript JDK and jQuery.
But even with a timeout of 10 seconds I get this error message:

**FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init().**

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.2.3.pack.js" />
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js">  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('document').ready(
    function(){
        FB.init({
                status : true, 
                cookie : true, 
                xfbml  : true 
        });

        setTimeout(function(){

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.session) {
                      jQuery('div#likeButtonWhatsThisText').remove();
                }
            });         
        }, 10000)       
    }
    )
</script>
```

Any ideas on how to get this work?

thanks christian

Comment: I bet the error message is just wrong, and that what's happening is that your "init" call isn't doing something necessary for the next call to work.

Answer (score 23):

Hi I think you are calling fb.init without passing your application ID. It should be like this

```
FB.init({
        appId: "Your API ID",
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
});
```

I hope this will work.

Comment: I'm still getting this error sometimes, even though I do specify my appID. Any one knows of any other reasons this might happen?

Answer (score 6):

Not a pro at this but have you tried:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', yourFunc);
```

And yourFunc should have one arg (response) where you check:

```
response.status == 'connected'
```

Answer (score 0):

call the init() function like this, it is working for me.

```
FB.init({
        appId: 'Your App ID',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.10',
    });
```