# Facebook like box get an error FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the module "facebook like box" in my homepage:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

I put this code immediately after `body` tag and I put this in left side:

```
<div class="fb-like-box fb-box-laterale" href="http://www.facebook.com/RistorantiRomaRisto.it" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/platform" data-width="190" data-height="380" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="false" data-header="true"></div>
```

All works done, but I receive this error in console: `FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()`

I've just read other conversation where i read that "You need to load the api asynchronously" and I followed their instructions with no result.

How can I solve it?

Comment: This might be a bug: now that we can access insights for a website without having to create an app. see: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/413087498764232?browse=search_50d2bd95ef9230a19542503

Comment: possible duplicate of [FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509971/fb-getloginstatus-called-before-calling-fb-init)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happen because you don't add an appId to the url you set for facebook.

See the complete code Facebook generate here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

As you'll see, the url is written like this: `//connect.facebook.net/fr_CA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID`

The presence of this appId, will automatically call `FB.init()` with basic app settings. But as you removed it, FB isn't calling it's init function, and call `.getLoginStatus()` directly.

So, go create a app for your website, and add the app Id to the code snippet in order to remove this error.

Hope this help !

Comment: i've try to get code from your website but i recevie the same code that i've posted without APP_IP, where i can get APP_ID ?

Comment: I'm getting the same annoying JS error. I just used that page re-generate the FB like code, and there is no reference to the app_id in the url. "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1".

Comment: mpoisot - you need to create an app for your page (via the link above), then, when logged in with that account active, the generator should add the APP_ID